# How can I reset deployment credentials in Windows Azure?

Tags: git, azure, deployment

I'm attempting to deploy to Windows Azure via git.

I have created a site, but I do not know the 'deployment credentials' used to push via git. I make a username for deployment when I created a site:

```
Please provide the username for Git deployment
```

But I do not know what the password for this user is. Attempting to use the Windows Azure UI to reset the deployment credentials tries to load a page that 404s:

[image]

- How do I know the password for the 'deployment credentials'?
- How can I reset my deployment credentials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

log in azure management portal, select your website - >dashboard.

there's a menu on right side. Just select the option reset your deployment credentials.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I found this eventually. I wish they'd just fix it.

Answer (score 4):

You'd normally set the password when adding git, but --git and adding local git repos crash the web UI. So the password is some random thing.

- Click **Sites** -> **siteName** -> **Dashboard** -> **Download the publish profile**
- This is an XML file. You want the first 'userPWD' (the one for 'web deploy', not the one for FTP). The password is very, very long.

Note the username Azure told you to add to git is likely wrong. Eg, when doing a `site create`, I received a message:

```
git remote add azure https://x@x.scm.azurewebsites.net/x.git
```

Instead, add a $ to the stat of the username

`git remote add https://$@x.scm.azurewebsites.net/x.git`

Comment: Downvoter: I appreciate the web UI now works but downvoting past 0 for a genuinely helpful answer is rude.